# Tensorflow alternative to crop_and_resize for tpu

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I have tried to use [crop_and_resize](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/crop_and_resize) in order to get a way of zooming into particular areas of an image as an attention mechanism for fine-grained image recogntion.

I am doing this on a TPU though, and when trying to train I'm getting an error saying that the operation is not available.

So I'm trying to come up with a way to take a batch of images, and a batch of corresponding bounding box co-ordinates, and return crops resized to the size of the original images.

I couldn't figure out how to do that as an operation on the full tensors so I tried a loop:

```
result = tf.Variable([tf.image.resize(images[0][tx[0]:tx[0]+tl[0], ty[0]:ty[0]+tl[0], :], [1200, 1200])])
for i in range(1, tf.shape(images)[0]):
    result = tf.concat([result, [tf.image.resize(images[i][tx[i]:tx[i]+tl[i], ty[i]:ty[i]+tl[i], :], [1200, 1200])]], axis=0)
```

So in words I'm doing the following:

1. Initialising a variable with the resized crop of the first image in the batch (wrt the corresponding bounding box)
2. Looping over the rest of the batch and concatenating onto my variable.

This works fine if I run it as a standalone script, but doesn't work when trying to train or predict with a model:

```
ValueError: "result" has shape (1, 1200, 1200, 3) before the loop, but shape (2, 1200, 1200, 3) after one iteration. TensorFlow control flow requires it stays the same or be more specific.
```

Does anyone know the right way to do this? Could I do the crop operation without having to loop?

I'm also wondering if Tensorflow is going to know how to back-propagate on this.

BTW I am using Tensorflow 2

Comment: Can I learn which particular areas you are zooming? Is it 4 corners of the image or just random locations?

Comment: @colt.exe thanks for the link! very helpful. The areas I'm zooming in on are determined by a bounding box regression from the features of a cnn. The result is then fed into a second cnn, and so on. If you're interested check out figure 2 on [this paper](http://openaccess.thecvf.com/content_cvpr_2017/papers/Fu_Look_Closer_to_CVPR_2017_paper.pdf). If you've get a better suggestion for how to approach it would be happy to hear it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/customization/performance#consistent_shapes_and_types) will make it clear for you. Tensorflow wants all loop variables stay consistent with each iteration. So concatention to a tensor and growth is not allowed. You have to define a larger tensor and fill it within a loop.